# Cannot Join String in Angular 2 Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some problem in my code might be type casting issue. I just want to join my String.

```
setValuetoComboBox(test:String, lvl:number){
    var lastTest:String;
    var spaceString:String;
    //&#160;
    spaceString='&#160';
    for(var i = 1; i <= lvl; i++){
        spaceString=spaceString + '&#160';
    }
    lastTest = spaceString + test;
    return lastTest;
}
```

usually, i use operator "+", but now it's error. the error is

[image]

Please help my problems, Thanks

Comment: You may try using `String.concat()`. However in this case, you may want to use `String.repeat()` before joining

Comment: please give me some example for your instruction, can u ?

Comment: Add your error text in a code block. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/how-to-write-code-in-a-question-or-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change String to string.

```
setValuetoComboBox(test:string, lvl:number): void {    
    let lastTest:string;
    let spaceString:string;
}
```

By the way , this is a typescript question and has nothing to do with Angular2 and components and ... .

And you really should stop using var and replace them with let or const.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, now my code really work